# ssh keeps throwing me out

Tags: ssh

I can't access my client's server over ssh even from the console. It looks like it let me in and then trow me out. Here is my session with the verbose option (I've changed my IP with 192.168.0.1):

```
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@192.168.0.1's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.0.1 ([192.168.0.1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Last login: Fri Dec  2 03:26:47 2011 from gateway.web.net
Usage: ipaliases {start|stop|restart|reload}

debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to 192.168.0.1 closed.
Transferred: sent 2448, received 2232 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 9160.2, received 8351.9
debug1: Exit status 1
```

From a recovery console I mounted my disk and made sure firewall is disabled. Can anyone help me on this? Also, I don't understand what the ipaliases message above means.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `/etc/profile` or root's `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` has an `ipaliases` command in it, which isn't being called properly (hence the `Usage: ...` line). Without seeing those files, it's hard to say for sure, but that would be where I would look first.

If you can, log on as another (non-privileged) user, try to run `su -` to gain root privileges and have a look at the above files for any `ipaliases` commands.

Comment: You were absolutely right, I have found that ../init.d/ipaliases was called from /etc/bashrc. It should have been called with the 'start' argument. /etc/bashrc was called from .bashrc. Thank you!